# The ice maker metal line going from the back of the fridge that’s connect to the shut off valve will not connect to plastic shut off valve 1/4?

Tags: plumbing

The metal nut from the ice maker maker line won’t connect to plastic shut off valve. It just turn and slides off unless I remove the washer but then the water squirts out if I do that.  I tried plumbers tape but still won’t hold or catch what should I do?

Comment: wrong size nut..

Comment: Got pics to help us help you?